# Are there (cheap) boat trips / water taxis / water buses across the Corniche bay in Doha?

Tags: ferries, qatar, doha

One of the focal points of Doha is the Corniche, a 5km long curved bay, running from the new Museum of Islamic Art round past lots of high-rise buildings to by the Sheraton. It has some stunning views across, as you walk round, like this:

[image: View across the Corniche in Doha]

In many cities with a waterscape like this, there are cheap-ish ways to cruise across and see it from the water. Sometimes it'll be a water taxi, sometimes a water bus, sometimes a short boat trip.

However, the [wikivoyage page](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Doha) doesn't seem to mention anything about that in Doha, and I didn't spot any today when I was walking along the Corniche.

Are there any cheap ways to see the Corniche and bay from the water? Or is the only option to just walk round? (Walking round does have nice views!)

Comment: What's 'cheap' to you?

Comment: Based on similar cities, I was hoping for something in the USD 5-20 range. Hopefully enough for a cheap group trip, or a water bus or taxi, but not enough to cover a boat charter / similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Water Taxis are Late

There are talks about a water taxi service currently being set up. [The reference I found](http://dohanews.co/karwas-water-taxi-sailing-date-postponed-to-late-2014/) talks about it being supposed to start in 2012, but being delayed to the end of 2014. To date, this is still a work in progress.

> The head of state-backed transportation firm Mowasalat has said a new QR30 million (US$8.24 million) water transit service – linking Lusail, the airport, Banana Island and the West Bay/Pearl area – should launch by the end of next year (Ed. 2014).

### Dhow Cruises

Nevertheless, the Doha skyline can be observed from the sea by taking a daily cruise around Doha Bay in a traditional wooden dhow. The cruise usually lasts for 4-5 hours, and will take you around various sites, giving you the chance to photograph all you want, while resting between snorkeling excursions. There are also dining and moonlight cruises, if you wish to spice it up. Various such services exists, [most of which are findable on google](https://www.google.fr/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=B7KqVMHwLYOBVPvogMgL&gws_rd=ssl#q=dhow%20cruise%20doha).

These cruises are probably not cheap in the way you intended in the question (I found one quoting QAR260.00). Moreover there might be a restriction to the minimum number of people required for the boat to set sail.